# How to do dynamic padding in a website

Tags: html, css, padding

Hey there i have the following question:

In my website i have a overhead div, and i want all the links in this div be padded in between the padding of the rest page, as it is in Stackoverflow.com f.ex. Here an image of what i mean:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/2qDXT.png]
(Im sorry, since the page is not realeased yet i dont want to show off my content.)

My problem is that, with the scale of the browser the padding has to be different everytime to bring the links to the right position, has anybody an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Use percentage for the `width` and `padding`!

Say you have a `.wrap` and you do this way:

```
.wrap {width: 90%; margin: 0 auto;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/utafem/1/

Comment: i get what you mean, but i want the horizonal green background to go over the whole page, i want only the text and images to be wrapped. EDIT: i just solved it, i made another div in the div. THX for your help